# linux sigtimedwait issue

Tags: linux, signals

I try yo use sigtimedwait according to the code below, I got this message "Caught unexpected signal 4714397, error 0, code 370078816". Does anyone know where I can the corresponding map of those number?

```
    sigset_t oMask;
    siginfo_t oInfo;
    struct timespec oTimeout;

    /* Create a mask holding */

    sigemptyset(&oMask);
    sigaddset(&oMask, SIGINT );
    sigaddset(&oMask, SIGTERM );

    /* Set the mask for our main thread to include SIGINT */

    pthread_sigmask( SIG_BLOCK, &oMask, NULL );

    /* Max wait for ^C set to 5 seconds */

    oTimeout.tv_sec = 5;
    oTimeout.tv_nsec = 0;

    int iRet = -1;
    bool bStop = false;
    while (!bStop)
    {
        iRet = sigtimedwait(&oMask, &oInfo, &oTimeout);
        if ( -1 == iRet && EAGAIN == errno)
        {
        }
        else
        {
            switch (oInfo.si_signo)
            {
            case SIGINT:
                printf( "Caught SIGINT in sigtimedwait( )\n" );
                bStop = true;
                break;
            case SIGTERM:
                printf( "Caught SIGTERM in sigtimedwait( )\n" );
                bStop = true;
                break;
                /* Should never really get to default */

            default:
                printf( "Caught unexpected signal %d, error %d, code %d\n", oInfo.si_signo, oInfo.si_errno,oInfo.si_code),oInfo.si_code) ;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you may be missing some logic there. If you get an error return of -1 but `errno` is *not* `EAGAIN`, you seem to assume it worked and the `oInfo` variable contains valid data.

This may cause a problem if your process is interrupted during the wait, since [one of the valid return codes](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/sigwaitinfo.html) is `EINTR`.

In that case, `oInfo` is going to contain whatever rubbish was on the stack when you entered that function, something borne out by the fact that I'm pretty certain signals don't go up to 4714397 :-)

Simple way to find out: print out `iRet` and `errno` in your default case.

There's also something hideously wrong with your line:

```
printf( "Caught unexpected signal %d, error %d, code %d\n",
    oInfo.si_signo, oInfo.si_errno,oInfo.si_code),oInfo.si_code) ;
```

but I'm going to assume that's just a typo on your part and it's really something like:

```
printf ("Caught unexpected signal %d, error %d, code %d\n",
    oInfo.si_signo, oInfo.si_errno, oInfo.si_code);
```

The change I would make to it would be:

```
printf ("Caught unexpected signal %d, error %d, code %d, errno %d, iret %d\n",
    oInfo.si_signo, oInfo.si_errno, oInfo.si_code, errno, iRet);
```

Comment: Thanks. after I change "if ( -1 == iRet && EAGAIN == errno)" to "if ( -1 == iRet)", I try to print out iRet and errno. I found it print error code 4 (EINTR) and then 11 (EAGAIN) and keep print EAGAIN. actually in what situation, EAGAIN is kept thrown?

Comment: `[EINTR] The wait was interrupted by an unblocked, caught signal. It shall be documented in system documentation whether this error causes these functions to fail.` - that _may_ mean you have to set up all the stuff again, rather than just continuing to call `sigtimedwait` as in the `EAGAIN` scenario.